# How does gRPC handle requests from the same client concurrently?

Tags: go, grpc

I was reading gRPC tutorial (https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/basics/#bidirectional-streaming-rpc) and found the following code:

```
1  func (s *routeGuideServer) RouteChat(stream pb.RouteGuide_RouteChatServer) error {
2    for {
3     in, err := stream.Recv()
4     if err == io.EOF {
5       return nil
6     }
7     if err != nil {
8       return err
9     }
10    key := serialize(in.Location)
11                 ... // look for notes to be sent to client
12     for _, note := range s.routeNotes[key] {
13       if err := stream.Send(note); err != nil {
14         return err
15       }
16     }
17   }
18 }
```

My current understanding from reading the code is that, when a request A from client is received in line 3, server proceeds to line 4 - 16 to handle that request, and this is a blocking process. If the client sends request B immediately after A is sent, the server cannot receive and handle it until request A is done processing.

So if processing A takes a very long time and B is a request to stop processing A, then the code will need to first finish processing A before starting to stop processing it, which is weird. I thought the code in this case should be something like:

```
1 func (s *routeGuideServer) RouteChat(stream pb.RouteGuide_RouteChatServer) error {
2    for {
3     in, err := stream.Recv()
4     if err == io.EOF {
5       return nil
6     }
7     if err != nil {
8       return err
9     }
10    if GetTypeofRequest(in) == A {
11         go HandleRequestA(stream)
12    } else if GetTypeofRequest(in) == B {
13         go HandleRequestB(stream)
14    }
15   }
16 }
```

Then in HandleRequestA and HandleRequestB, stream sends different responses.

I was under the impression that gRPC should recv and handle requests concurrently and doesn't require such goroutines. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: This handler represents a streaming connection. Each chunk from stream.Recv is part of the same request. Concurrent requests would run the whole handler a second time, I guess.

Comment: @TheFool so even without the goroutines in second piece of code, request B can be handled by the server and then, for example, interrupt the processing of request A?

Comment: I assume that this method is invoked as goroutine for each request, the same way http handlers are run as goroutine. Thats more or less the standard behavior you would expect from a server thingy. So there is no need to interupt.

Comment: @TheFool So, if the purpose of request B is to stop the processing of request A, the server can handle request B when A is being processed, and (try to) stop A accordingly?

Comment: I am not sure if I can follow your use case.  Perhaps this is a XY problem. You can have a look here for example https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/v1.49.0/server.go#L864.

Comment: @TheFool I'll go check it out, thank you very much